# I want to restart a circular progress bar after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
const useProgress = (maxTimeInSeconds = 30) => {
    const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
      const intervalId = setInterval((callback) => {
        if (progress < 1) {
          setElapsedTime((t) => t + 1);
        }
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      setProgress(elapsedTime / maxTimeInSeconds);
      console.log(elapsedTime);
    }, [elapsedTime]);

    return progress;
  };
  const progress = useProgress();
```

Here I have implemented logic to move the circular progress bar for 30 seconds. What I want to do is restart the progress after 30 seconds and keep it in the loop for 30 seconds.

here I have pasted the whole code

```
import { Observer } from "mobx-react";
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Platform,
  Dimensions,
  Clipboard,
} from "react-native";
import * as Progress from "react-native-progress";
import AppStore from "../../stores/AppStore";
import Iconpack from "../../utils/Iconpack";
import Theme from "../../utils/Theme";
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";
import CircularProgressBar from "./CircularProgressBar";
import { Shadow } from "react-native-shadow-2";
import Toast from "react-native-simple-toast";
import { BoxShadow } from "react-native-shadow";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
// import Clipboard from "@react-native-community/clipboard";
const hRem = AppStore.screenHeight / 812;
const wRem = AppStore.screenWidth / 375;

const OtpDetails = ({ route, params, navigation }) => {
  const { id, title } = route.params;
  const useProgress = (maxTimeInSeconds = 30) => {
    const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
      const intervalId = setInterval((callback) => {
        if (progress < 1) {
          setElapsedTime((t) => t + 1);
        }
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(elapsedTime);
      setProgress(elapsedTime / maxTimeInSeconds);
      if (elapsedTime == 30) {
        setProgress(elapsedTime / maxTimeInSeconds);
      }
    }, [elapsedTime / maxTimeInSeconds]);

    return progress;
  };
  const progress = useProgress();

  const setTextIntoClipboard = async () => {
    await Clipboard.setString(title);
    Toast.show("OTP copied successfully!", 200);
  };
  const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getModel();
  return (
    <Observer>
      {() => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FastImage
            style={styles.container}
            source={Iconpack.GLOBAL_BG}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
          />
          <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("OtpScreen");
              }}
            >
              <Image
                style={styles.backButton}
                source={Iconpack.GLOBAL_BACK_BUTTON}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>{title}</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image
                  style={[styles.editTrashButton, { marginRight: 19 }]}
                  source={Iconpack.EDIT_ICON}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image
                  style={styles.editTrashButton}
                  source={Iconpack.DELETE_ICON}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.circleOuter}>
            {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
              <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                <Progress.Circle
                  style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                  progress={progress}
                  // indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
                  size={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.561}
                  thickness={10}
                  borderWidth={0}
                  endAngle={10}
                  strokeCap="round"
                  color={"#354659"}
                  // indeterminateAnimationDuration={1}
                  unfilledColor={"#031830"}
                />
              </View>
            ) : (
              <Shadow
                distance={20}
                startColor={"rgba(27, 100, 206, 0.5)"}
                radius={210}
                safeRender={true}
              >
                <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                  <Progress.Circle
                    style={{ alignItems: "center", overflow: "hidden" }}
                    progress={progress}
                    // indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
                    size={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.561}
                    thickness={10}
                    borderWidth={0}
                    endAngle={10}
                    strokeCap="round"
                    color={"#354659"}
                    indeterminateAnimationDuration={2000}
                    unfilledColor={"#031830"}
                  />
                </View>
              </Shadow>
            )}

            <Text style={[styles.circleItem]}>{title}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                setTextIntoClipboard();
              }}
              style={styles.copyItem}
            >
              <Text style={styles.copyText}>TAP TO COPY</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          {/* <View style={styles.circleOuter}>
              <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.circleItem}>title</Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  copyToClipboard();
                }}
                style={styles.copyItem}
              >
                <Text style={styles.copyText}>TAP TO COPY</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity> */}
          {/* </View> */}
        </View>
      )}
    </Observer>
  );
};

export default OtpDetails;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#021831",
  },
  headerStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 56 : 40,
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 26.66,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backButton: {
    width: wRem * 12,
    height: hRem * 21,
  },
  editTrashButton: {
    width: wRem * 23,
    height: hRem * 23,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed2,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontWeight: "600",
    marginLeft: wRem * 50,
  },
  circleOuter: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  circleContainer: {
    borderRadius:
      Math.round(
        Dimensions.get("window").width + Dimensions.get("window").height
      ) / 2,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.56,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.56,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    shadowColor: "rgba(27, 100, 206, 0.5)",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 30,
    shadowRadius: 30,
  },
  circleItem: {
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed7,
    textAlign: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    paddingBottom: 100,
  },
  copyItem: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: hRem * 64,
  },
  copyText: {
    color: "#3D4756",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed4,
  },
});
```

with all styling and the most important thing is I am using third party party library react-native-progress thanks

Comment: If you're writing a TOTP app, shouldn't the visual component be driven by the actual time to the expiry of the code, not... the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`progress` does not need to be a state atom since it's always unambiguously calculable from the elapsed time and max time.

Using the modulo (remainder) operator you can have the observed progress always loop back to 0 after the maximum time.

```
const useProgress = (maxTimeInSeconds = 30) => {
    const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
        useEffect(() => {
            const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                setElapsedTime((t) => t + 1);
            }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);
    return (elapsedTime % maxTimeInSeconds) / maxTimeInSeconds;
};

const progress = useProgress();
```

Alternately, if you want slightly more accurate, wallclock-based timing:

```
const useProgress = (maxTimeInSeconds = 30) => {
    const [initialTime] = useState(() => +new Date());
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter((t) => t + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);

    const elapsedTime = Math.floor(((+new Date()) - initialTime) / 1000);
    if (elapsedTime == 30) {
        return maxTimeInSeconds;
    }
    
    return (elapsedTime % maxTimeInSeconds) / maxTimeInSeconds;
};
```

This pins the progress start to the component's mount time, and should work better even when `setInterval` isn't accurate.

Comment: thanks a lot, but when it reaches 30 seconds it's coming back and it starts again what I want is, It will continuously keep moving clockwise @AkX

Comment: What would be moving clockwise? There's no visual element in here.

Comment: pls find the whole code

Comment: I really appreciate your response but  having one issue, progress bar started at 0 and it ends at 28 seconds, and then it comes back, it does not reach 30 seconds at all @AKX

Comment: If this is for a (T)OTP app, you should not rely on `setInterval` anyway – there's no guarantee it will be run exactly 1000 msec apart.

Comment: is there any way to change with new logic, which I have given in code @AKX

Comment: See my edit for a possibly more accurate version.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, it's working the same as previous if there is any answer would be love to hear @AKX

Comment: hey, I am so close like what i  have done is maxTimeSeconds }